# efficient update of GL state given a change to the scene

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

Suppose we have a scene which consists of a list of n meshes in draw order. The triangle count of each mesh is bounded by a constant (though that constant may be large). Also suppose we have GL state such that all meshes can be rendered with a single draw call (glDrawArrays/Elements).

Given a change to the scene, which may consist of:

- Inserting a mesh in the list
- Removing a mesh from the list
- Changing the geometry of the mesh (which may include changing its triangle count)

**Is there a O(1) way to update GL state for a single change to the scene?**

Answer (score 0):

Because of the draw-order and single-draw-call constraints, the meshes must be laid out linearly in a VBO in that order. Thus, if a mesh is inserted in the list, the VBO must be resized by moving data, which is not O(1).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an OpenGL problem. The work complexity has to do with how you model geometry, which happens well before you start trying to shove it into a GPU.

But there are some GL-specific things you can think about:

- Separate vertex array order from draw order by using an index buffer and a DrawElements call. If you're drawing multiple entities out of one vertex buffer and you expect them to change, you can leave some padding in the vertex buffer and address vertices by index.
- Think about how you're getting that vertex data to the GPU if it's changing every frame. For example, with double- buffering or MapBufferRange, the CPU can work on filling a buffer with new vertex data for the next frame while the GPU draws the current frame from a different buffer (or range).

The work you do to arrange/modify vertices every frame still can't be O(1). GPU work (and CPU/GPU transfers) tends to be thought of more in ms than order analysis terms, but there are things you can to minimize time.

Comment: I was looking for O(1) per change to the scene, not per frame. Essentially, I was hoping there's a way to use a single draw call without moving lots data around in the vertex buffer in response to a scene change. DrawElements at least moves that problem over to the index buffer, which is smaller.